# Send Email with lettre and body with Handlebars.js

Tags: rust, handlebars.js

This is on my Rust the handlebar initialization. There are not errors.

```
  let mut reg = Handlebars::new();
  let order_email_content = reg.render_template("src/emails/order_email.hbs", &serde_json::json!({"data" : email_order.body, "orderNumber": 3333, "amount": 555})).unwrap();
```

Here is lettre for sending emails:

```
let host_email = Message::builder()
      .from(config.email.serverEmail.email.parse().unwrap())
      .to(config.email.recipient.parse().unwrap())
      .subject("Rust Order für FlyerandPrint")
      .multipart(
        MultiPart::alternative() // This is composed of two parts.
            .singlepart(
                SinglePart::builder()
                    .header(header::ContentType::TEXT_PLAIN)
                    .body(String::from("Hello from Lettre! A mailer library for Rust")), 
            )
            .singlepart(
                SinglePart::builder()
                    .header(header::ContentType::TEXT_HTML)
                    .body(order_email_content),
            ),
    )
    .unwrap();
```

This passes but the email received includes only the string of the path.

I am newbie to Rust. Thanks.

Question: How could i include the html from handlebars(order_email_content) to use it on body of lettre?

Note: Printing reg (the handlebare variable) gives:

```
Handlebars { templates: {}, helpers: ["if", "lt", "raw", "or", "len", "unless", "with", "log", "lookup", "lte", "ne", "and", "not", "gt", "eq", "gte", "each"], decorators: ["inline"], strict_mode: false, dev_mode: false }
```

But printing order_email_content gives string `"src/emails/order_email.hbs"`

Comment: The handlebar documentation isn't very clear, but it looks like you need to first call [`register_template_file`](https://docs.rs/handlebars/4.1.5/handlebars/struct.Handlebars.html#method.register_template_file) to load the template file before calling `render_template`.

Comment: Thanks for answering, it seems i get on the email only the path of the file "src/emails/order_email.hbs", i tried register_templates_directory and register_template_file. So the mistake is probably on how i am using it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the examples in [the handlebar documentation](https://docs.rs/handlebars/4.1.5/handlebars/#rendering-something), something like this should work:

```
let mut reg = Handlebars::new();
reg.register_template_file ("email", "src/emails/order_email.hbs").unwrap();
let order_email_content = reg.render ("email", &serde_json::json!({"data" : email_order.body, "orderNumber": 3333, "amount": 555})).unwrap();
```

Or:

```
let mut reg = Handlebars::new();
let order_email_content = reg.render_template (
   include_str!("src/emails/order_email.hbs"),
   &serde_json::json!({"data": email_order.body, "orderNumber": 3333, "amount": 555})).unwrap();
```